# Upgrading old .NET project from .net framework 4.0 to 4.7.2 and to TLS 1.2

Tags: .net, tls1.2

I need guidance. I know how to upgrade .net to 4.7.2, but the solution I'm working on has 100+ projects, so I want to know what it entails to do this upgrade, code changes? Proprietary NuGet packages will be affected?

And then, the TLS part. I'm lost on that, I did some research, I know what TLS is and why it's needed, but I can't yet get how it's implemented in .net projects. My questions on it: how do I know what version of TLS my current application is running on? How can I upgrade it to 1.2 without having it hardcoded in my projects? Do I need to change TLS configuration for each of my projects or could it be done per solution?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: NuGet packages have already migrated away from .NET Framework 4.0, *several* years ago - support for 4.0 ended 6 years ago. Even your own projects aren't using it any more - .NET Framework 4.x runtimes are binary replacements which means installing a new runtime, eg through Windows Update or another application, replaces the machine's existing runtime

Comment: As for TLS - you don't have to do anything to "implement" it. The network stack does this. When you call an HTTPS URL, TLS is used automatically. Since .NET Framework 4.6.2 the runtime uses the best algorithms provided by the operating system (assuming you use a supported Windows version, ie 10 and later). If your app runs on Windows 10, you get TLS1.2 automatically. On Windows 11 you get TLS1.3.

Comment: The real differences are elsewhere. .NET Framework 4.0 is 12 years old. You shouldn't have waited so long. There's no `yes but` here - major online services moved to TLS1.2 *in 2016*. PCI DSS certification requires TLS1.2 for years too. .NET 4.5 introduced some breaking changes, eg in some types of URL encoding. These are documented [in the migration guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.5), There are a lot of SO questions about this too. The real problem will be third-party libraries, eg NuGet packages. In 10 years they've changed *completely*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is some great insight, what if a lot of my machines are running on Windows Server 2008? Those will run by default on maybe 1.0/1.1 TLS, as per the company rules we need to make those run on 1.2. Is that reasonable? What needs to be done in that case? Just upgrading those to say 4.7.2 will be enough? And I suppose I'll need to somehow upgrade all used NuGet packages too?

Comment: Regarging `major online services moved to TLS1.2 in 2016.` - I worked for an online travel agency at the time that found every possible (unfounded) excuse to delay migration from 4.x to 4.5 at the time. What if there are problems, yes but it will take too long, blah blah. Then Sabre, the online service used by every OTA to search for and book flights, announced it will demand TLS1.2 in just 6 months time. We had to migrate everything, in a panic mode, in just a couple of months

Comment: `what if a lot of my machines are running on Windows Server 2008?` That 14-year old OS is way past its End-Of-Life. Again, there are duplicate SO questions. You'll have to patch those machines. This is explained in [TLS 1.2 Support added to Windows Server 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2017/07/20/tls-1-2-support-added-to-windows-server-2008/). This patch is available through Windows Update which means that either it's already installed, or the machines aren't being patched

Comment: Mhmm, ok understood! Thanks a lot for the insight was great help! Will continue my research and take by your advice!